# Making remote desktop available over internet

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop

I just recently finished installing Ubuntu desktop. I want to be able to, on my windows PC, connect to my ubuntu-pc via remote desktop. I did manage to access it locally (As long as I'm on the same router) but I have not been able to connect to it from work or such. I've opened ports `5900` and `3389` but that didn't make any visible difference.

How can I achieve this? I've installed xRDP and XFCE4 on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: You could give ssh a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I forgot to open all ports necessary with the correct IP..

Issue was simply that on Apple's router settings, you need to put in the IP of the computer that's going to have the specified port opened. The IP I put in was my macbook's IP and not my servers' IP.

Comment: If you were to [edit] this answer to detail how you did it, it could be useful for future readers of this Q&A who may benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

On your Ubuntu desktop, go to connection information and take note of your IP address. Also, take note of the Ubuntu desktop's username in the about section in System Settings. Then, download Windows Remote Desktop from the Windows Store, enter username@(ip-address here with no parenthesis), and then it will connect to the desktop.

Comment: I know how to use remote desktop.. And usually how to connect. Thing is you need to set up a server on the ubuntu desktop that can host RDP and VNC connections. That's what I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/)
it really solves any hassle.

Comment: I was thinking about doing so aswell, but I sort of feel like that's a work-around. Anyhow, I managed to get xRDP working just fine! :)